# Why doesn't the increment operator (++/--) work while using the ternary if/else operators?

Tags: java, if-statement

Similar to the bellow question, however I'm expanding with more specific inquiries.  Also, this is setting aside opinions on whether or not to use the ternary or normal styling of if/else's.
[Applying increment using ternary operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197150/applying-increment-using-ternary-operator-in-java)

So in theory, the following snippet:

```
if (text.equals("foo"))
    data++;
else if (text.equals("bar"))
    data--;
```

should look like this using the ternary operators:

```
data = text.equals("foo") ? data++ : text.equals("bar") ? data-- : data;
```

However, in my android (Java) application, android studio showed me a warning:

> The value changed at 'data++' is never used

Like-wise, when I ran this in my application, the data variable stayed the same. However, when I changed the line of code to this:

```
data = text.equals("foo") ? data + 1 : text.equals("bar") ? data - 1 : data;
```

It worked.

So, this makes me wonder if the ++/-- operator is allowed within this context? 
 Does anyone have any input on this?

Comment: `++` _after_ the variable, is applied _after_ the assignment. Try using `++data` and `--data`.

Comment: Why not `data += text.equals("foo") ? 1 : text.equals("bar") ? -1 : 0` to remove all the confusion? Well, remove as much confusion as possible while still using nested ternaries.

Comment: Discussion of whether this should be `if` or ternary is very relevant here, though. The assignment back to `data` here is not just wasteful (given that `++` and `--` already change `data` to what you believe it should be), but actively a source of a bug; this should without question be an `if` statement unless you are trying to make your code unmaintainable (besides some nanoseconds slower).

Comment: compiler knows that `data++`  does not have any effect on your code `data++` indicates that values is first assigned then incremented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post-increment (`data++`) and post-decrement (`data--`) operators return the value of the variable prior to its increment/decrement, so assigning it back to the variable cancels the increment/decrement.

You can use pre-increment and pre-decrement instead (or `data + 1` and `data - 1` as you did):

```
data = text.equals("foo") ? ++data : text.equals("bar") ? --data : data;
```

Answer (score 0):

because it only check the condition and return the answer as condition is true or false it  cannot work with increment decrement operator if you really want to apply increment decrement in that you can apply  loop in  and in that condition you place on count operation if count increment then increment operation is performed otherwise it performed decrement operation

Comment: Could you explain why a loop would be needed?

Answer (score 0):

In ternary operators, if you break it down, it will be

```
if(text.equals("foo")){
data = data++;
} else if(text.equals("bar")){
data = data--;
} else {
data = data;
}
```

And you are using post incremental and decremental operator on variable, which is assigned to itself. This can be break as

```
data = data++; This can be seen as 
int temp = data; 
data = data +1;
data = temp;
```

And same with the post incremental case. So in every case data value will not change.
With example

```
data = 10;
int temp = data;// temp = 10;
data = data + 1; // data = 11;
data = temp; // data = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also remove the assignment from the statement and it will works fine. i.e.

```
text.equals("foo") ? data++ : text.equals("bar") ? data-- : data;
```